# How to read a text file for tuples

Tags: python

I have a text file of the form

```
plot:('neg', 0.4023264475292897)
derek:('pos', 0.5849625007211561)
is:('pos', 0.003209556475890097)
male:('pos', 0.49749965947081676)
model:('pos', 0.7004397181410923)
```

I'm trying to load this file into a dictionary of the form

```
{'plot':('neg', 0.4023264475292897), 'derek':('pos', 0.5849625007211561)}
```

with the key being a string and the tuple being string, float.
I have tried using tuple(value) when splitting by the colon but it's not working properly as I don't know how to separate the other characters so the tuple includes every space and quote in the text file.Like so

```
def load_model(filepath):
dictionary = {}
with open(filepath, 'r') as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        (key,value) = line.split(':')
        dictionary[key] = tuple(value)
return dictionary
```

it would show up as 'partnership': ('(', "'", 'p', 'o', 's', "'", ',', ' ', '1', '.', '0', ')', '\n') in the dictionary isntead of 'partenrship': ('pos', 1.0)

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Ask]

Comment: Please search on this question first. I am seeing lots of similar question in StackOverflow.

Comment: If you do see a duplicate question, why not put a link or links in your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values are simple tuples, I would consider using the built in [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module and parse them with [literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast

with open(path) as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split(':')
        d[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
```

The dictionary `d` will then be:

```
{'plot': ('neg', 0.4023264475292897),
 'derek': ('pos', 0.5849625007211561),
 'is': ('pos', 0.003209556475890097),
 'male': ('pos', 0.49749965947081676),
 'model': ('pos', 0.7004397181410923)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're splitting by the colon, you get

```
x.split(':')[1] # ('key', val)
```

Since they are read as text, you can

```
1) Strip the leading and trailing brackets.
2) Split again on comma
3) Remove quotes on key, convert val to number
4) Pass both into a tuple.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you in that **for** loop?

```
for line in textfile:
    (key,value)=line.split(":")
    value2=value[1:-2].split(",")
    value2[0]=value2[0].replace("'","")
    value2[1]=float(value2[1])
    key=key.replace("'","")
    dictionary[key]=value
```

There maybe a simpler way (and indeed some of the commands here could be chained), but it's past midnight here; best I could do. :-)

Comment: Perhaps: `{m[0]: (m[1], float(m[2])) for line in textfile for m in [re.search(r"(.+)\:\('(.+)'\s*\,\s*(\d*\.\d+)\)", line).groups()]}`. Assuming the `re` module has been imported.